# Strange `tinytex` behavior - `~/.TinyTex` keeps dissapearing?

Tags: r, docker, tinytex, tex-live

In my `rocker/rstudio`-derived `docker` container, I'm engulfed in a quagmire surrounding the yearly TexLive update and the `R` package `tinytex`.

I have gone through a plethora of iterations of `tinytex::install_tinytex()`, `tinytex::uninstall_tinytex()`, `tinytex::reinstall()`, etc.

I have installed the most current version via `remotes::install_github("yiuhi/tinytex")`.

I have experimented with different (up to date) mirrors of `CTAN`.

When using a up to date mirror and having `installed`/`reinstalled` `tinytex` properly, I keep getting this behavior:

```
> tinytex::tinytex_root()
[1] "/home/rstudio/.TinyTeX"
> tinytex::pdflatex("<MYFILE>.tex")
tlmgr: package repository http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: koma-script [13745k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
tlmgr: package log updated: /home/rstudio/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
```

... 6 more successful package installs ...

```
tlmgr: package repository http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: babel-english [3k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
tlmgr: package log updated: /home/rstudio/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
! LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly.

! sh: 1: pdflatex: not found

Error: LaTeX failed to compile <MYFILE>.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See <MYFILE>.log for more info.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  error in running command
2: In system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : error in running command
> tinytex::tinytex_root()
[1] ""
```

After this, `~/.TinyTeX` (which was present before) is literally GONE from the file system!?

Can anybody shed light on why 1) `tinytex` appears to install, 2) it appears to properly process my `*.tex` file and pulling in the appropriate packages from `CTAN` and than 3) proceeds in one of those package installations to delete it's entire own installation!?

Comment: I experience a similar behaviour on my machine, which is really strange. I do not see the "NFSS system" error, but simply `! Package Listings Error: Couldn't load requested style.`

Comment: Now at `github` as well: https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/197#issue-600851259

Comment: My apologies for this really bad bug! Should be fixed on Github now: https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/197#issuecomment-614895625 If it works for you, I'll make a CRAN release soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observed behavior was a bug in the `tinytex` `R` package and has since been resolved (https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/197).

Until the `CRAN`-available version is >= 0.21.5, one may remedy the behavior by installing directly from the author's repository by:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("yihui/tinytex")
```

Comment: FYI tinytex 0.22 is on CRAN now: https://cran.r-project.org/package=tinytex